# Constrain View Issue

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I'm trying to make OTP login screen and ran into some issue

following is my XML code. I've used `ConstraintLayout` and `RelativeLayout` in this single activity. I did not write any java code yet but `setContentView()` is also defined

if you look closely to my output you can see the white rectangle on top-left

I think the issue is with XML I might have done something wrong please help

```ja
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="97.71dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="135dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="29dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
        android:src="@drawable/verification"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="211dp"
        android:layout_height="34dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="27dp"
        android:text="@string/content"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#898A8F"
        android:textSize="11sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/relativeLayout3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
        tools:ignore="SmallSp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout3"
        android:layout_width="322dp"
        android:layout_height="154dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="48dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="48dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="48dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="48dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="275dp"
        android:background="@drawable/background"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.571"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
        tools:targetApi="lollipop">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="17dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ed_txt_bg"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/flag"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/num"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#313450"
            android:textSize="19sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />


        <EditText
            android:layout_width="216dp"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="83dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="83dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ed_txt_bg"
            android:importantForAutofill="no"
            android:inputType="text"
            tools:ignore="LabelFor" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="280.9dp"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="17dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="95.56dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
            android:text="@string/submit"
            android:textColor="#fff" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[This is suppose to be Output](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JpKDSRP2pVX7Yt0jVXLIdYYgP6CmjQdS/view?usp=drivesdk)

[But this happens when I run it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8pET.jpg)

can you tell me how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

you can try following code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        app:cardElevation="6dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:ems="3"
                android:hint="+91"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <EditText
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:text="1234567890"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/editText"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
                android:text="@string/submit"
                android:textColor="#3C3F41"
                app:backgroundTint="#03A9F4"
                app:cornerRadius="24dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:text="Enter your mobile number, we will send you otp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/cardView2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="85dp"
        android:layout_height="85dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Add material dependency to your project and replace your images and ids for views.